# Sqlite percentage using GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

I have some data which contains "Currency Pair" (like EUR/USD,SPX500/USD etc) and Pl among other info. I can  obtain the wins using

```
    SELECT "Currency Pair", COUNT(Pl) AS Win FROM data  WHERE Pl>0.01
    GROUP BY "Currency Pair";
```

while the total number of operations is given by

```
    SELECT "Currency Pair", COUNT(Pl) AS Total FROM data  WHERE ABS(Pl)>0.01
    GROUP BY "Currency Pair";
```

Now I would like to print a table like

```
    Currency Pair     Win   Tot   Success rate
    ---------------   ---   ---   ------------
    EUR/USD             3    11   27.27
    SPX500/USD          6     8   75.00
```

But unfortunatly I'm not able to correctly calculate the percentage and neither to print Win and Tot on the same table. My main problem is to pass two different WHERE.

As alternative way I tried

```
   SELECT "Currency Pair",
   COUNT(CASE Pl WHEN Pl>0.01 THEN 1 ELSE NULL  END) AS WIN, 
   COUNT(Pl) AS Total  FROM data WHERE ABS(Pl)>0.01
   GROUP BY "Currency Pair";
```

But while the total number is correct I have zeros on the win column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) has two forms:

- `CASE SomeValue WHEN X1 ... WHEN X2 ...`, where `SomeValue` gets compared with each `X`, and
- `CASE WHEN Condition1 ... WHEN Condition2 ...`, where each boolean `Condition` gets evaluated independently.

In your query, you have the value `P1`, which gets compared against the value `P1>0.01`, which is the result of the comparison, i.e., `0` or `1`.

You want to use the second form instead:

```
... COUNT(CASE WHEN Pl>0.01 THEN 1 END) ...
```

(Note: ELSE is not needed because NULL is the implied default.)

Comment: Thank you so much.
For some reasons COUNT(P1>0.01) doesn't work
but 

       COUNT(CASE WHEN Pl>0.01 THEN 1 END) AS Win,

       COUNT(CASE WHEN ABS(Pl)>0.01 THEN 1 END) AS Total

It's working fine.

Comment: Sorry, that comparison wouldn't result in NULL.